# JiraPS PowerShell Module / new-jiraissue issues

Tags: powershell, jira, jira-rest-api

I've been looking at this for a few hours and I'm banging my head against the desk.

I keep getting this error:

```
Invoke-JiraMethod : 
customfield_10806 components 
----------------- ---------- 
Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object. data was not an array
```

Script:

```
New-JiraSession -Credential $Credentials -Verbose #-Debug
$field = @{
'components' = @{
id = 10303
}
'customfield_10806' = @{
id = 10704
}
}
New-JiraIssue -Project 'PROJECT' -IssueType '4' -Fields $field -Summary "Test Summary Created by $($env:username) in PowerShell" `
-Description "Test Summary Created by $($env:username) in PowerShell" -Reporter 'REPORTER' -Verbose -Confirm:$false
```

If I add `-priority 4` to the script I get:

```
Invoke-JiraMethod : 
priority 
-------- 
Field 'priority' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
```

My head is getting sore from banging my head against the desk.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

---

Not sure why my formatting in my comments isn't sticking, but there's the solution in case anybody else stumbles upon this and needs help.

```
New-JiraSession -Credential $Credentials -Verbose
$fields = @{
    Project = 'PROJECT'
    IssueType = 4
    Summary = "Test Summary Created by $($env:username) in PowerShell"
    Description = "Test Summary Created by $($env:username) in PowerShell"
    Reporter = 'REPORTER'
    Fields = @{
        'customfield_10806' = @{'value' = 'Low'}
        Components = @(
        @{
            name = 'NAME'
        })
        }
        }

New-JiraIssue @Fields -Verbose
```

Comment: Does it work when you remove `Priority` argument? Can you manually create Jira issue with the same fields?

Comment: No, it then gives me an array error.  I edited the post just now to show that.

Answer (score -1):

```
New-JiraSession -Credential $Credentials -Verbose
$fields = @{
    Project = 'PROJECT'
    IssueType = 4
    Summary = "Test Summary Created by $($env:username) in PowerShell"
    Description = "Test Summary Created by $($env:username) in PowerShell"
    Reporter = 'REPORTER'
    Fields = @{
        'customfield_10806' = @{'value' = 'Low'}
        Components = @(
        @{
            name = 'NAME'
        })
        }
        }

New-JiraIssue @Fields -Verbose
```